# QT5 and Antlr4.8 not Compiling with Cmake and QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, antlr4

As in the above im trying to compile a QT5 project inside of QT Creator with cmake and want to add the antlr package.

Infos: Qt 5.12.8, Antlr 4.8, Compilers tried: mingw gcc|g++ , msvc 2015,2017
System: Windows / Linux both do not work

For including Antlr 4.8 i use the provided CPP Package to build Antlr from Source

This is the project i am working on.
https://github.com/MrDiver/ArmSimulator/tree/ArmParser/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor

i include antlr4 with the following https://github.com/MrDiver/ArmSimulator/blob/ArmParser/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/CMakeLists.txt#L14-L21

and normally it works perfectly fine when i compile something with it. But this time when i try to include the header files for antlr i get this error message

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/AsmEditor.dir/managers/processormanager.cpp.obj 
H:\Programme\QT\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\g++.exe  -DANTLR4CPP_STATIC -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I. -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor -IAsmEditor_autogen/include -Iantlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/armparser/assembler -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/armparser/walker -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/codearea -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/managers -IH:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/armparser -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/include -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/include/QtWidgets -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/include/QtGui -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/include/QtANGLE -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/include/QtCore -isystem H:/Programme/QT/5.12.8/mingw73_64/./mkspecs/win32-g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/AsmEditor.dir/managers/processormanager.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\AsmEditor.dir\managers\processormanager.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/AsmEditor.dir/managers/processormanager.cpp.obj -c H:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/managers/processormanager.cpp
In file included from antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/antlr4-runtime.h:31:0,
                 from H:/MyStuff/PrivateProjects/CPPProjects/ArmSimulator/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/managers/processormanager.cpp:2:
antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/Lexer.h:116:46: error: invalid declarator before 'newToken'
     virtual void emit(std::unique_ptr<Token> newToken);
                                              ^~~~~~~~
antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/Lexer.h:116:46: error: expected ')' before 'newToken'
antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/Lexer.h:123:25: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
     virtual Token* emit();
                         ^
[30/31 0.6/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/AsmEditor.dir/armparser/assembler/ARMParser.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
18:59:55: The process "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project AsmEditor (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.8 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "CMake Build"
```

File of Interest: https://github.com/MrDiver/ArmSimulator/blob/ArmParser/src/asmeditor/AsmEditor/managers/processormanager.cpp

Seems pretty much like it can't find `std::unique_ptr<Token>` but i can't change a lot about this, because these are the antlr sources and they actually work.

So i don't really know anymore where to search for the problem. The library itself compiles fine if i choose it as target in the settings.

What i tried:

- Compiling the antlr library outside and just linking it in the cmake file.
- Changing the `Lexer.h` file with `#include <memory>`.
- Compiling the QT project without QT Creator (Resulting in a ton more errors because i cant get the linking for QT to work)
- Compiling every Antlr related file outside of the project (Works perfectly fine without QT but not really what i need)
- Using different compilers and different Systems.
- Searching for a problem with `moc` but it doesn't seem to influence it. But i doubt i looked hard enough on moc for this.

And im quite new to QT so i don't know everything what the Qt Creator does behind the scenes. It seems like too much if i can't compile it with plain cmake out of the box.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try add `add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)` and see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Antlr has methods like "emit" that conflict with the Qt reserved word "emit". The solution is to disable the flag "no_keywords" (in qmake add `CONFIG += no_keywords`, and in CMake add `add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)`) as indicated by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots). Then you must make the following conversions:

```
emit to Q_EMIT
slot to Q_SLOT
slots to Q_SLOTS
signal to Q_SIGNAL
signals to Q_SIGNALS
```